# developer command prompt for VS2013--- " "is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: c#

I want to run it with  command prompt---CLDemo one two three

```
using System; 

class CLDemo  
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(args.Length ); 
        for(int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
             Console.WriteLine(args[i]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: using System;
class CLDemo {
static void Main(string[] args) {
Console.WriteLine(args.Length );
for(int i=0; i < args.Length; i++)
Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
}
}

Comment: The developer command prompt doesn't let you run your own programs via the prompt, its for developer "tools" (not things you make yourself). If you want to run your program yourself from the command prompt, you have to navigate to the debug or release directory (in the command window) where your `CLDemo.exe` file is located and run it from there.

Comment: i wont to add letter "one two three"  in  (string[] args)     sorry my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project in Solution Explorer, select Properties. There, in Debug tab, is a place for entering command line arguments when debugging.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1ktzfy9w(v=vs.100).aspx